# Why is part_1.js, part_2.js showing up in my assetic compiled code

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic

When i compile my code using assetic my js files are being named part_1.js, part_2.js.  i dont see this referent to part_ anywhere in my code.  where is this coming from?

config.yml

```yml
assetic:
     assets:
         our_custom_js:
            inputs:
                - '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/base.js'
            filters:    []
            output: 'custom.js'
         fos_js_routes:
             inputs:
                 - 'bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js'
             output: 'fos_js_router.js'`
```

base.html.twig

```
{% javascripts combine=false output="sandbox.js"
    '@our_custom_js'
    '@fos_js_routes'        
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>

{% endjavascripts %}
```

my source ends up looking like this

```
<script src="/sandbox_part_1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData"></script>
<script src="/sandbox_part_2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData"></script>
```

This question was also asked here [How to make Symfony 2 asset compilation to product different filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911072/how-to-make-symfony-2-asset-compilation-to-product-different-filenames)

Comment: i may have commented on that post, but my reputation is messed up.  i dont feel this is deserving.  anybody hvae any to share so i can comment and answer questions which im currently banned from?

Comment: I could be wrong but the parts are only used when in the `dev` environment. Are you accessing the site using `app_dev.php`? and if so do you still have the `part_` files when accessing using `app.php`?

Comment: i was in dev env , yes.  you know im not sure if i was seeing them on app.php now.  It only happens when i use the assetic naming to call the files '@our_custom_js'  so i left that config in assetic: for compiling reasons, but call it by name only now just so its named correctly `bundles/mybundle/js/base.js`.  Even if its only happening in dev, its still cryptic, and bothersome that theres no control over it, until someone finds the config magic to overcome it.  I spent all day on assetic config getting to the bottom of filter problems, and naming problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31404649/1405981). The 'part_#' string is added when accessing your application in the development environment (`app_dev.php`).

By default, `{% javascripts %}` will print all your assets/scripts, using a `<script>` line for each script. In the production environment, they are combined.

The `{% javascripts %}` function acts like a `foreach` loop in dev environment, while it will combine all assets in to a single `<script>` line in production. If you take a look at the PHP-script in the documentation, you can see that it's using `foreach`:

```
<?php foreach ($view['assetic']->javascripts(
    array(
        '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*',
        '@AcmeBarBundle/Resources/public/js/form.js',
        '@AcmeBarBundle/Resources/public/js/calendar.js',
    )
) as $url): ?>
    <script src="<?php echo $view->escape($url) ?>"></script>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Your base.html.twig should look like this:

```
{% javascripts combine=false output="sandbox.js"
    '@our_custom_js'
    '@fos_js_routes'        
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
    <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

When the other `<script>` is not inside the `javascripts` part, it will not be in the loop, so it will be printed only once.